# Confusion regarding implementation of token based authentication [Node js Express js]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, git

After all the research on authentication methods related to nodejs and express js, I am standing in no man's land.

By far the easiest session related tutorial I have come across is this.

https://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/manage-session-using-node-js-express-4/

I am using mean stack and this is what I really want to do. The user when logins will get an authentication token that will be saved on the client side and then before every page reload a call will be made to the server to check if the user is authenticated or not.

Here comes the tricky part.

I am using the server to work for Computer - that is angular based system and cellphone which is based on android - an android application.

In short that means a user may login using his computer and cellphone as well (using the application) at the same time.

How to implement this is still a mystery for me. Please direct me to some tutorials or gits which will explain this things in simplest possible means.

Please don't respond with passport js only because I have failed to find anything meaningful there, or maybe it is possible that I am looking at the wrong place.

I am new to all this that is way this problematic.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is for all the beginners out there. I read something similar in facebook's node js group and I think the problem I am facing is not unique.

The passport js which is very famous just works as a middle ware and if you have to include options like google authentication, facebook authentication etc. this is very useful as most of the work is already done and your middleware work is handled by this module.

But if like me you are searching for something simple and all you want is a proper authentication system with database then this might not be necessary, this = passport js module.

You are surely depending on one more module which is complex as well, if you want to implement token based authentication. In the end if you are handling all the authentication work in the middle by yourself, why should you use a module as well which increases complexity in the end.

I even took suggestion from other node js developers who have worked on this for good amount of time and they think it is okay to head without passport js if you are ready to work with middleware yourself and you don't need fb etc. authentication.

I hope this will help others who are new to all this.

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way to implement the token based authentication is to use `oAuth2.0` which also involve use of `passport JS`

Here , use this example as a reference point for implementing the token based authorization

http://scottksmith.com/blog/2014/07/02/beer-locker-building-a-restful-api-with-node-oauth2-server/

This sample code have fully functional `OAuth2` server done with just a little bit of work. it uses `OAuth2orize` library that makes building server very straightfoward.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned that you are using Angular and NodeJS and want to implement Token Based Authentication.

I would suggest you use [Satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer).

Also you can find NodeJS implementation over here:
[NodeJS Example](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/tree/master/examples/server/node).

Answer (score 0):

Since the question referred to my article directly. Here is the token based implementation using Node.js as the answer.

https://codeforgeek.com/2016/08/token-based-authentication-using-nodejs-rethinkdb/

Hope it helps.